# Digitizing deceased friends tape; reel-to-reel RCA audio plugs to USB

Tags: imac, usb

I am trying to digitize reel-to-reel tapes of a deceased friend talking and singing. The problem is how to connect from two RCA audio output plugs to a USB so I can connect to the digitizing software on the 2020 iMac. Does anyone know what to do?